# I cannot pass of the first print

Tags: python, python-2.7

Please someone can help me, because I do not found where is the mistake.

Please do not be mean with me I am just learning I only want to know How I solve this problem.

I have a mistake on this code because I put after each **while** and **if** a **print**, then, when I run the code only the first message is printed.

This is part of the code, I called the file 'test':

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import serial
datosOEM=bytearray(5)
print(datosOEM)
datosOEM[0]=65
print(datosOEM)
x=[0]*6
...
k=0;
trama=1;
B=0;
C=0;
conexion=True;                 
if(conexion):
    #{
    print ('conexion ON')
    while(response<200):
        print ('data save')
        while(C==0):
            #{
            print ('what is C?')
            x[0]=datosOEM[k];
            if(x[0]==1):
                #{
                print ('what is x1?')
                x[1]=datosOEM[k+1];
                ...
```

When I run the file 'test.py', this is that I see

```
A
True
Port opened...
Data sent
inside while
"something" # This data change everytime that I run the code
conexion ON
```

To conclude I need your help with one thing:
**locate the mistake on the file 'test.py'**

Please do not be rude with me I am just learning

**###########################################################**

In the form that I have the original post the viewers give me a **-6**

I just edit this post with a new name, **PLEASE**, I beg to the others viewers that vote "Like", because this page I am using to complete my thesis

Comment: Why is this question tagged "java"?

Comment: sorry, I think add some java here, but I decide put the Java part in a separate post

Comment: Please try to minimize your post to the core problem, and choose an apppropriate title for it. Right now, this question isn't a good one at all.

Comment: After you read the post. What do you recommended?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
print ('conexion ON')
while(response<200):
```

`response` is a string ("something" in your debugging output). You are comparing it
to an integer.  In some implementations of Python, [integers always compare "less than" strings](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3270689/153430), and it looks like that's why the loop is getting skipped in your case.

Comment: then, How I fix the problem?

Comment: Don't compare strings with integers?

Comment: Thank you very much because I did not know that. Now I fix that problem changing all "response" after the "is" for "resp". Now I have other problem in line 62: IndexError: bytearray index out of range.